# Split the string if matches Double quotes using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var test = 'This is the text with "UserName" and "Password"';
```

To split the test(string) using regex

I tried like this `test.match(/"[^"]*"|\S+/g);`
it returns : `[This,is,the,test,with,UserName,and,Password]`

i dont want to split each word,

expected result =  `['This is the text with','"UserName"','and','"Password"']`

Comment: Could you please make sure you type correctly the regex you used?

Comment: I have tried     test.match(/"[^"]*"|\S+/g);

Answer (score 1):

The `\S+` matches any 1+ chars other than whitespace. You may fix the expression to match what you need if you replace `\S+` with `[^"]+`:

```js
var s = 'This is the text with "UserName" and "Password"';
console.log(s.match(/"[^"]*"|[^"]+/g));
// Or, trim each item, too:
console.log(s.match(/"[^"]*"|[^"]+/g).map(x => x.trim()));
```

It seems you may also use a *splitting* approach if you wrap the `"[^"]*"` pattern with a capturing group to force the `split` method to also output the texts captured (note you may need to remove empty items later with e.g. `.filter(Boolean)`):

```js
var s = 'This is the text with "UserName" and "Password"';
console.log(s.split(/\s*("[^"]*")\s*/).filter(Boolean));
```

Note that `\s*` are added to the pattern to trim off whitespace from around the double quoted substrings.

Comment: It's working fine can i use multiple characters with this split
like the string = 'This is the text with {"UserName"} and {"Password"}';

Comment: @YuvaMac Sure, [you can](http://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/erfqsbvn/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the `split` method and pass your regex. check code

```js
var test = 'This is the text with "UserName" and "Password"';

var a = test.split(/"/ig)
console.log(a)
```